# Pandas .mean() method from .pct_change() returns nan value

Tags: python, pandas, mean, series, yfinance

I am currently trying to get the mean of a pandas series representing the percent change of another pandas series that is the percent change of the original series; however, when I try to get the mean by using `acc.mean()` it returns `nan`. This is not the case for `pct_returns.mean()` which returns the mean. Also, both of these series plot correctly ([pct_returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Uf3z.png), [acc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WODSm.png)) with pyplot so I am unsure why I cannot take the mean correctly.

Here is some sample code as an example:

```
import yfinance as yf, pandas as pd, numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

tick = yf.Ticker('AAPL')
data = tick.history('5y')

data_prices = data['Close']
pct_returns = data_prices.pct_change()
print(pct_returns.mean())

plt.plot(pct_returns)
plt.show()

acc = pct_returns.pct_change()
print(acc.mean())

plt.plot(acc)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is nothing to compare it against, the first element returned by `pct_change` is NaN.  You need to exclude the first row.  Maybe:

```
print(acc.dropna().mean())
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html

Answer (score 0):

Because your `acc` contains positive and negative infinity, which are impossible to add together:

```py
>>> acc.agg(['min', 'max'])

min   -inf
max    inf
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

You get those values when `pct_returns` is close to 0. Division by 0 returns `inf` or `-inf` according to the [IEEE 754 Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754):

```py
>>> pct_returns[np.isclose(pct_returns, 0)]

Date
2017-12-22    0.0
2020-07-02    0.0
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

---

To elaborate: `mean = sum / count` (NaNs are ignored - they neither go to sum nor count). So the issue is with the sum.

```py
# When the sum is NaN, you can't calculate mean
>>> acc.sum()
nan

# Instead of an error, division by 0 result
# in +inf or -inf in numpy and a warning
>>> np.divide(1, 0), np.dvide(-1, 0)
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  np.divide(1, 0), np.divide(-1, 0)
(inf, -inf)

# Infinity plus or minus anything is still infinity
>>> np.inf + 100, -np.inf - 100
(inf, -inf)

# Infinity plus negative infinity result in nan
# They don't cancel each other
>>> np.inf + -np.inf
nan
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will need to look for this in the future. As a follow-up question: is replacing all `pct_returns` elements that are equal to zero with `nan` values the best/most accurate way to handle this problem?

Comment: You are measuring percent change in percent change, which is the perplexing part for me. But yes, removing the 0 in`pct_returns` would solve this problem

Comment: Yes, I switched from pct_change and opted for np.diff() so I could have actual values and not percentages. Also, I chose to replace the inf and -inf values by using: `acc.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)`